# Is there a Rails helper to show array content or its count if greater than X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

I'm looking for a Ruby on Rails view helper which:

- take an Array as argument
- behave like `to_sentence` (http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence) in the case the size of the Array is lower than a given parameter
- behave like `pluralize` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize)in the case the size of the Array is lower than a given parameter

For example:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > ["Audit", "Porsche", "Peugeot"].to_sentence("car", limit: 3)
 => "Audit, Porsche, and Peugeot"
2.0.0p247 :002 > ["Audit", "Porsche", "Peugeot", "Mitsubishi"].to_sentence("car", limit: 3)
 => "4 cars"
```

If this kind of helper doesn't exists I can create it but I would avoid to duplicate something existing.

Comment: It's really useless this -1... Anyway thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP has asked for a one word answer, however useless that is, the answer is:

> No.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a helper.  You can just use a conditional in the view:

```
<% if array.length < min %>
  <% array.to_sentence(...) %>
<% elsif array.length > max %>
  <%= array.length %><%= string.pluralize %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much for this quick answer, but the question is (yes or no) there is a Rails helper which do what I have described :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little shorter version

```
<% a = ["Audit", "Porsche", "Peugeot"] %>
<%= a.size < 4 ? a.to_sentence : a.size.to_s + " cars" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the short version.